# Serve two pages from two server for one url

Tags: caching, cookies, nginx, browser-cache

I would like to serve two different pages from two servers for one url. Something like facebook does with login page (login page vs profile page on same url).

How will server know what page to serve? I went with cookie because I couldn't think of other solution.

Also cookie removal is needed on logout. I ended up with branch on nginx configuration to push request to right server and removing(setting expired time) cookie there.

Ok and now the bug itself. Chrome caches this url and when user clicks on link(to the same url) chrome skips request to the server and open wrong version from cache. It works when "disable cache" in debug panel is checked and I also confirmed this by checking traffic with wireshark.

To recap urls from browser point of view:

```
ex.com/                - Server A
ex.com/login_check     - Server A -> redirects to / with cookie
ex.com/                - Server B
ex.com/?logout         - Server A and remove cookie
ex.com/                - chrome skips request and serves cached content from B
```

How can be this fixed? Moreover this approach looks like too much magic and many things can go wrong. Could it be done differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding header for response from both servers.
`Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store;`